# Adafruit PAM8302A -> Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: gpio, audio, raspbian-stretch, adafruit

I want to connect [Adafruit PAM8302A](http://adafru.it/2130) amplifier to the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+.

What I need?
How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll down that page you linked to, in the learn section there a quite a few projects that use that board with the raspberry pi. [One of them includes these instructions](https://learn.adafruit.com/10-raspberry-pi-desktop?view=all):

> PAM8302 Audio Amplifier:
>
> GPIO #1 (3V) on the Pi connects to VIN on the PAM8302. GPIO #9
>   connects to GND on the PAM8302. The +Postive and -Negative connections
>   are wired to the A+ and A- on the PAM8302.
>
> The Audio jack plugs into the audio port on the Pi.

Looking through some of the others should be helpful too.

Comment: What are the wires?

Comment: @Minecon724 What wires? And have you read the resource that T.M. links to above?

Comment: Yes, I've fully read

Comment: @Minecon724 Then you need to improve your question to be a lot more specific. I've linked to one set of instructions that answers your question, and showed you where to find more. Please see how to ask a good question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question above. Otherwise this should be closed.

Comment: "the wires" are lengths of conductive material, usually copper, encased in a plastic insulation material. A small amount of  each *end* of such *wire* has the *insulation* stripped, and the exposed copper is connected to the appropriate spot, using an appropriate *connector* - hope this clears up what *wire* is